# How can I set the selected value of a dropdown using a smarty variable

Tags: frontend, smarty

I have a list of suppliers and a defaultSupplier assigned to a template, I add the suppliers to a dropdown and iterate through them using a foreach and I try to make the default selected value depending on the defaultSupplier like this:

```
                        <select name="supplier_id" id="supplier_id" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" data-show-tick="false">
                        <option value="" {if $defaultSupplier eq ""}selected="selected"{/if}>-- {"Choose a supplier"|t} --</option>
                        {foreach $suppliers as $s}
                            <option value="{$s.supplier_id}" {if ($defaultSupplier == $s.supplier_name)}selected="selected"{/if}>{$s.supplier_name}</option>
                        {/foreach}
                    </select>
```

But it doesn't work, I get the "Choose a supplier" option selected then I have to manually select my supplier from the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

I had to close the page and navigate on it again and it worked